# C# Replace 1+ occurences of char by 1char

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I haven't an idea how replace 1+ occurences of "\" in path with only 1 "\"

Example:

```
C:\\\ProgramFiles\\New Folder\TestFolder\\Test\\\
```

and after replace it should be like:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\New Folder\TestFolder\Test\
```

But there can be more occurences of "\" than 3

Comment: replace \\ by \ as long as there is \\ in the string

Comment: It was only for backslash in paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Regular Expression to match any number of consecutive `\` characters with a single one with the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
// This will replace any number of consecutive slashes with a single slash
var output = Regex.Replace(input,@"\\+","\\");
```

You can [see a working example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZfoXzK).

Additionally if you are looking at these paths within the Visual Studio debugger, it's worth noting that they are commonly going to appear with their associated escape characters (an extra `\`), which may not actually be there in the final string itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked exacly how i wanted.
I work on some kind of Mini Total Commander program and user can give his own path. And i had problem when he add to many backslashes and try to go back when he was already in root.